# How to save cropped image using openCV?

Tags: python, image, opencv, crop, face-recognition

I am capturing image using opencv and face_recognition library in python,
Here is the snippet of my program

```
while True:
ret,frame = video_capture.read()
rgb_frame = frame[:,:,::-1]
face_locations = fr.face_locations(rgb_frame)
face_encodings = fr.face_encodings(rgb_frame,face_locations)
cv2.imwrite('test.png', frame)
if len(face_encodings)!=0:
    print(face_locations)
    temp = list(face_locations[0])
    img = cv2.imread('test.png')
    cropped = img[temp[0]:temp[2],temp[0]:temp[1]]
    cv2.imshow("cropped", cropped)
    cv2.imwrite('face.png',cropped)
```

I am trying to save cropped image to my directory. But the code above doesn't work. Do you know the way how can I save cropped Image using opencv ?

Comment: what does it mean does not work, does not save at all or ends up with error or saves somewhere else than you intend?

Comment: what about temp[3]?

Comment: I am sorry , it has been succeeded thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `cv2.imwrite('path/to/face.png',cropped)`